# How to check if a url belongs to a website that exists?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am making a website where in a form, users can input a web page address. I was going to go with checking if the url is formatted correctly like an actual url which I think is the sloppy way and instead I want to check if url belongs to an actual website. Like, let's say user inputs www.pyrtyrmyrsyr.org, that is a valid address, but it doesn't lead to a website. Let's say user inputs www.python.org, that is both a valid address and leads to a website that exists.

And how can I check this validity before the form is sent and after input is given? Make the form's "send" button not clickable if url is not valid?

**EDIT : Realized I didn't add any code of my view, apologize for that, also forgot to mention I use Bootstrap for View.**

This is the form I use, what I am trying to do is use "Check" button, to check validity, by taking URL inside form-control with "id=url"

```
<div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h2 style="margin-left:20px; margin-top:10px">Add a Link</h2>
            <form action="~/Link/Create" method="post">
                <div class="form-group well clearfix" style="margin-left:20px; margin-right:20px; margin-top:20px">
                    <br />
                    <div class="row">
                        <label for="name" class="col-lg-2">URL:</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-9">
                            <input class="form-control" id="url" placeholder="URL" name="Address" /><br />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-1">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="checkurl">Check</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-2">
                    <label for="name">Interval:</label>
                        </div>
                    <!--<div class="col-lg-10">
                        <input class="form-control" placeholder="Interval to check (minutes)" name="Interval" /><br />
                    </div>-->
                    <div class="col-lg-5">
                    <select class="form-control" id="sel1">
                        <option>Minutes</option>
                        <option>Hours</option>
                        <option>Days</option>
                        <option>Weeks</option>
                        <option>Months</option>
                    </select>
                    </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-5">
                            <select class="form-control" id="sel2">
                                <option>Minutes</option>
                                <option>Hours</option>
                                <option>Days</option>
                                <option>Weeks</option>
                                <option>Months</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                    <button class="btn btn-success pull-right" type="submit" style="width:200px; margin-right:15px">Save</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As far as I searched so far, connection to another domain/website is not possible using Javascript or anything similar so I need a server-side language, so I need to take this url, send it to control and return a true/false value after checking connection.

Comment: At a rather abstract level, you can do a check on two things. 1. Make sure the url is matched by a regex that matches URLs - there are quite a few of these readily available for you to use online. 2. Make sure that website can give you a proper http get response - also plenty of resources online to help you figure out how to do that.

Comment: @TolgaAçış sounds like you need to check a tutorial about forms and POST in ASP.NET MVC. This is the default functionality - when you submit a form the controller action you specified is calld, passing the field values in the body. These appear as parameters on the action. Anything you want to return should be passed as a model to the View result

Comment: @TolgaAçış a more advanced scenario would be to validate the URL on the browser using Javascript. Regex validation is already available. You could add your own script that calls the URL to ensure it's accessible from the browser.

Comment: Solutions go in the answer section, not the question (I have rolled back your changes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it:

Added a bool to my model:

```
    public bool Valid { get; set; }
```

Changed my view a little:

```
<div class="row">
    <label for="name" class="col-lg-2">URL:</label>
        <div class="col-lg-9">
            <input class="form-control" id="url" placeholder="URL" name="Address" /><br />
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-1">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" id="checkurl">Check</button>
         </div>
             <input type="hidden" name="Valid" id="Validity"/>
</div>
```

Used the following codes, one for checking validity, other to reset form being usable if input is changed

```
$('#checkurl').click(function () {
    var address = $('#url').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Control/CheckUrl",
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify({ url: address }),
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        error: function (xhr) {
            alert('Error: ' + xhr.statusText);
        },
        success: function (result) {
            if (result) {
                document.getElementById("Validity").value = true;
                document.getElementById("saveBut").disabled = false;
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById("Validity").value = false;
                document.getElementById("saveBut").disabled = true;
            }
        },
        async: true,
        processData: false
    });
});

$('#url').change(function ()
{
    if (document.getElementById("saveBut").disabled == false)
    {
        document.getElementById("Validity").value = false;
        document.getElementById("saveBut").disabled = true;
    }
});
```

Ajax code there leads to a controller function that reformats URL a bit and checks validity:

```
public ActionResult CheckUrl(string url)
{
    try
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(url)) return Json(false, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); ;
        if (url.Equals("about:blank")) return Json(false, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); ;
        if (!url.StartsWith("http://") && !url.StartsWith("https://"))
        {
            url = "http://" + url;
        }
        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        string HTMLSource = wc.DownloadString(url);
        return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return Json(false, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

It works flawlessly and as desired.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Remote Validation in Asp.NET MVC. Let you have following property in your model.

```
public string URL {get; set;}
```

Add Remote attribute to your property like

```
[Remote("YourAction", "YourController", HttpMethod = "GET", ErrorMessage = "URL is not valid.")]
public string URL {get; set;}
```

Now write the following code in your specified action of the controller.

```
public class YourController : Controller
{

        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult YourAction(string URL)
        {
            try
            {
               //Check here by hitting your URL using HTTPClient or WebClient that it is returning something or not.
                WebClient wc = new WebClient();
                string HTMLSource = wc.DownloadString(URL);
                return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); //Return true if it is valid.
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return Json(false, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); //Return false if it is not vald.
            }
        }
}
```

You must have to add following configurations in your web.config

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
</appSettings>
```

Your code on view will be like

```
 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.URL, new { type = "url", @class = "form-control", placeholder = "URL" } })
 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.URL, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

Comment: @TolgaAçış, That is what the `[Remote]` attribute does - it makes an ajax call to the method, which returns `true` or `false` and displays an error message in the `@Html.ValidationMessageFor()` placeholder (and the form cannot be submitted). Note that you do not 'disable' a submit button - you just prevent the submit and show an error which is what the attribute does

Comment: You might also want to read [How to: Implement Remote Validation in ASP.NET MVC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg508808(VS.98).aspx) for a more detailed explanation of the `[Remote]` attribute

Comment: @TolgaAçış. If you have a solution, you need to add it as an answer (not an edit to your question)

Comment: @TolgaAçış, What to you mean 'unlocking the form'. Read the answer carefully, and the link I gave you. You **do not** 'lock' a form (or disable the submit button). The validation attribute, in conjunction with the validation scripts prevent the form from being submitted if the method returns false - that is how it all works

Comment: And you really need to buy yourself a good book, or at least go to the MVC site and work through the tutorials to learn a few basics, in particular how to create a view and bind to your model (the M in MVC is for Model)

Comment: Solved it all, added answer